# My Flutter app wont run on android studio to ios simulator because Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: flutter, dart, ios-simulator

So the code just isn't launching, but the Xcode build is done but it fails to build the iOS app on the simulator. I'll give my run info and the part of the code that I changed that may have caused this. It may be because I need to fix the import statements, or update something, but I'm not sure.

### RUN INFO

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           105.2s
Failed to build iOS app
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
/Users/{name}/AndroidStudioProjects/{project-name}/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/permission_handler/permission_handler.framework: replacing existing signature
/Users/{name}/AndroidStudioProjects/{project-name}/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/permission_handler/permission_handler.framework: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed
Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
```

### CODE

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:email_validator/email_validator.dart';

import 'package:location/location.dart'; // location
import 'package:location_platform_interface/location_platform_interface.dart';


class setup_page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: thething1()
    );
  }
}
class thething1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _thething1State createState() => _thething1State();
}

bool _allowedAccessToAll;

class _thething1State extends State<thething1> {

  void requestPermissions() async {
    await Permission.contacts.request();
    await _location.requestService();
    await _location.requestPermission();
    await Permission.microphone.request();
    //await Permission.sms.request();

    //PermissionStatus _permissionGranted ;

    if (await Permission.contacts.request().isGranted
        && await Permission.location.request().isGranted
        && await Permission.microphone.request().isGranted
        //&& await Permission.sms.request().isGranted
    ) {
      setState( () {
        _allowedAccessToAll = true;
      } );
    }
  }

build function here
}
```